# Is it possible to assign a number to a lists with the same name to be differentiated?

Tags: netlogo

A part of my program relies on recording the lengths of roads within my user interface as they are drawn out. As this requires looping , and as I want to be able to keep the name of the list all the data is stored in the same, is it possible to create lists thusly :

```
 set list road-length X
```

(where  X is a counter that is incremented every time a condition is met). Essentially can I tag numbers on to the ends of lists so that I can tell them apart when they need to be read later on in my program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but it is almost surely the wrong approach. (For one thing, the names will not be global unless you declare them all ahead of time.)  Instead, use the `table` extension, create a global to hold your table, and use the table to map your id numbers to your lists.  This will prove much more useful.

Comment: Ok so once I have mapped a key to a list using a table, how can I  then retrieve the  key associated with the list?